# Pandas group by with sum on few columns and retain the other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table which look like this.

```
 msno      date  num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq  \
0   rxIP2f2aN0rYNp+toI0Obt/N/FYQX8hcO1fTmmy2h34=  20150513       0       0       0        0        1        1   
1   rxIP2f2aN0rYNp+toI0Obt/N/FYQX8hcO1fTmmy2h34=  20150709       9       1       0        0        7       11   
2   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150105       3       3       0        0       68       36   
3   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150306       1       0       1        1       97       27   
4   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150501       3       0       0        0       38       38   
5   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150702       4       0       1        1       33       10   
6   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150830       3       1       0        0        4        7   
7   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20151107       1       0       0        0        4        5   
8   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20160110       2       0       1        0       11        6   
9   yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20160316       9       3       4        1       67       50   
10  yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20160510       5       3       2        1       67       66   
11  yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20160804       1       4       5        0       36       43   
12  yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20160926       7       1       0        1       38       20   
13  yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20161115       0       1       4        1       38       40   
14  yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20170106       0       0       0        1       39       38   
15  PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=  20151201       3       3       2        0        8       11   
16  PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=  20160628       0       0       1        1        1        3   
17  PNxIsSLWOJDCm7pNPFzRO/6Mmg2WeZA2nf6hw6t1x3g=  20170106       2       1       0        0       35       34   
18  KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=  20150803       0       0       0        0       16       11   
19  KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=  20160527       4       3       0        2        2       11   
20  KXF9c/T66LZIzFq+xS64icWMhDQE6miCZAtdXRjZHX8=  20160808      14       3       4        1       15       31
```

How should I sum up the columns `'num_25', 'num_50', 'num_75', 'num_985', 'num_100', 'num_unq', 'total_secs'` to get the total and left only one unique msno number?

For example, after group all same msno number rows, it will produce result below, discarding date column.

```
msno        num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq  \
0    rxIP2f2aN0rYNp+toI0Obt/N/FYQX8hcO1fTmmy2h34=        9       1       0        0        8        12
```

I tried this but the msno still duplicated and date column is still there.

```
df_user_logs_v2.groupby(['msno', 'date'])['num_25', 'num_50', 'num_75', 'num_985', 'num_100', 'num_unq', 'total_secs'].sum()
```

Comment: Do you need assign output? `df = df_user_logs_v2.groupby(['msno', 'date'], as_index=False).sum()` if need summ all columns or `df = df_user_logs_v2.groupby(['msno', 'date'], as_index=False)['num_25', 'num_50', 'num_75', 'num_985', 'num_100', 'num_unq', 'total_secs'].sum()` ?

Comment: What do you mean by assign output? I tried both of the code and there is still multple identical msno instead of one. And the date is still there, I wish to take off the date as well, thanks

Comment: Hmmm, if groupby by both columns `msno` and `date` then get multiple `msn`. Do you need remove `date` ? Like `df_user_logs_v2.groupby('msno')['num_25', 'num_50', 'num_75',....` ?

Comment: I got it with solution like this.
`df_user_logs_v2.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)` then

`df_user_logs_v2 = df_user_logs_v2.groupby(['msno'], as_index=False).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `sum`:

```
df = df_user_logs_v2.drop('date', axis=1).groupby('msno', as_index=False).sum()
```